# Get key value from map from reference bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

Im trying to get map key value but from reference bean.

I have two classes. One contains two Maps other one need to read key value from this class an set own field.

```
@Data
public class ClassOne{

    private Map<String, Object> xxx;
    private Map<String, Object> yyy;

}
```

```
@Data
public class ClassTwo{
    private String zzz;
}
```

xml application context

```
<bean id="ClassTwo" class="...">
<property name="zzz" value="#{ClassOne.${xxx['key']} == 'myString' ? 'otherString' : false}"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="ClassOne" class="...">
<property name="xxx" value=""></property>
</bean>
```

my intention is to refer to bean ClassOne get a Map and get Map value by key

## {ClassOne.${xxx['key']} == 'myString' ? 'otherString' : false}

edit:

for this application context Im getting

```
   <bean id="ClassTwo" class="com.interns.pittaci.model.label.ClassTwo">
        <!--- for property name zzz from ClassTwo set value based on map called xxx with key 'test' inside ClassOne -->
        <property name="zzz" value="#{ClassOne.${xxx['test']} == 'test' ? 'test1 ' : test2}"></property>
    </bean>
```

following error message:

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
> Invalid bean definition with name 'ClassTwo' defined in class path
> resource [applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder
> 'xxx['test']' in value "#{ClassOne.${xxx['test']} == 'test' ? 'test1 '
> : test2}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> Could not resolve placeholder 'xxx['test']' in value
> "#{ClassOne.${xxx['test']} == 'test' ? 'test1 ' : test2}"

Comment: I would suggest losing the xml and using classes with annotations if possible. It makes a lot of these kinds of things a lot easier

Comment: Main reason why xml : this approach allow to edit conditional statements without accessing application code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is using ${} when accessing to the map because it is not necessary to use ${} when accesing a class atribute. Try `#{ClassOne.xxx['key'] == 'myString' ? 'otherString' : false}`

In addition to this, the ternary operator defined in application-context.xml is returning a boolean value in case that the key is not present in the map and trying to assign it to a String attribute

Comment: added error message and current application context . Apologize for editing original post.

Comment: I think the problem is use ${} when accessing to the map because it is not necessary to use $ when accesing a class atribute. Try #{ClassOne.xxx['key'] == 'myString' ? 'otherString' : false}